# How to get a program to repeat itself using a while loop and if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm really new to Python and I'm finding it really hard to understand certain aspects of the language. I've been asked to create a program for an assignment and after hours of trying to use this website, I've come to no avail.

The question is:
Write a program which uses a loop to take in the first name, last name and
telephone number from an undefined number of users. The program
should allow the user the option to quit, after each iteration of the loop. **The program should also write the information entered by the user to a text file called names.tx**

I have no problem with the part of the question in bold but I really can't wrap my head around the first bit. Here's what I have so far:

```
def main():

    infoList = []
    count = 0

while True:

    firstname = input('Please enter your first name: ')
    lastname = input('Please enter your last name: ')
    telephoneno = input('Please enter your telephone number: ')
    contiinue = input('Continue (y = yes): ')
    if contiinue == y:
        count = count + 1

main()
```

When the program is iterating itself again, I want the user to be able to give different details to the questions. I know people hate when people ask questions and it seems like they're just trying to get people to do homework for them, but this will genuinely bug me for a while if I am unable to find a resolution.

Comment: Did you mean for the while loop to be in the main() function? Then it and its body should all be indented to match the assignment statements.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here:

- Firstly, as Paul McGuire's comment says, your while loop is not properly indented; thus Python sees it as a separate part of your program file.
- Secondly, you have no way of leaving your while loop. If you're going to use a `while True` construct, you need a [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) statement somewhere; most likely, you'd want an `else` following the "then block" of your `if contiinue = 'y'` (another issue I originally overlooked was that you left out the quote marks there) with the `break` as the only line in the `else` block. Alternatively, you could do a test in the while which would stop the loop when some condition is reached. For example, you could pre-initialize your contiinue variable to 'y' (before the loop insert `contiinue = 'y'`) and change `while True` to `while contiinue == 'y'`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two separate questions:

### [Breaking out of a loop.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

You have two options:

1. A [`break` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) immediately ends the while loop. You can decide on something the user should type to exit (like `"q"` or whatever), check if they've typed it, and `break` if so.
2. While loops have an exit condition in their declaration, and you can use it for the same kind of exit command as above. For example:

   ```
   user_input = "default value"
   while user_input != "q":
       user_input = raw_input("Type 'q' if you want to exit!")
   ```

### [How to write data to a file.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Python has a builtin function called [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) which lets you interact with files.

`my_file = open("my_file.csv", "r")` will give you a file object in "r" mode (read-only mode); you can do things like `for line in my_file` to access its contents.

`my_file = open("my_file.csv", "w")` will give you a file object in "w" mode (write mode); you can write the contents of a variable into it by doing `my_file.write(my_data)`. Note that this *will* overwrite anything already in the file, so proceed with caution.

Once you're done with a file, make sure to close it using `my_file.close()`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You first need to indent the loop and its contents so that it will be recognized as a part of the main(), as it is, it is separate from main

For your while loop, you should use initialize continue to 'n' and change your while loop as follows `while continue == 'y'`, this will continue the loop until something other than 'y' is entered. You should also change `if continue == y:` to `if continue == 'y':` because y without quotes is a variable, not a char.

As for the text file, you should open the file before the loop, write to it as you go in the loop, and then close it. Since you are writing line by line, you also won't need infoList[] or count, since adding `\n` to the end of f.write() moves the line down.

```
def main():
    
    continue = 'n'
    f = open('names.txt','w')

    while continue == 'y':

        firstname = input('Please enter your first name: ')
        lastname = input('Please enter your last name: ')
        telephoneno = input('Please enter your telephone number: ')
        continue = input('Continue (y = yes): ')
        f.write(firstname + ' '+ lastname + ' ' telephoneno + '\n')

    f.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this (minimal change to your code):

```
def main():

    infoList = []
    count = 0

    while True:

        firstname = input('Please enter your first name: ')
        lastname = input('Please enter your last name: ')
        telephoneno = input('Please enter your telephone number: ')
        contiinue = input('Continue (y = yes): ')
        if contiinue == "y":
            count = count + 1
        else:
            break

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some code and comments to your code that should help you get started.

```
def main():

    infoList = []
    count = 0

    while True:

        firstname = input('Please enter your first name: ')
        lastname = input('Please enter your last name: ')
        telephoneno = input('Please enter your telephone number: ')
        # you probably want to append to infoList here
        contiinue = input('Continue (y = yes): ')
        if contiinue == "y": #make sure it's a string
            count = count + 1
        else:
            # figure out how to break from your loop
            # otherwise it will execute forever
    #outside the loop here so write everything in infoList here
    with open('names.txt', 'w') as f:
        #write to your file

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an outline only.

Try something like:

```
names=[]
counter=1
while True:
    name=input("name {} or 'q' to quit:".format(counter))
    if name.lower()=="q":
        break
    else:
        names.append(name)    
        counter+=1

print(names)
```